# changing the height of plot area in "plotOutput" in shiny based on the number of the figures(automatically)

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a " renderplot " function in the server section of Shiny that produces 1 to 4 figures.
how can I change the height of the plot area in the shiny app based on the number of the figures (automatically)?
I mean the height for 4 figures should be bigger than the height for 2 figures.
I used wight = "auto" , height = "auto" in the UI section but I got error. So I assign a fixed size to it (height = "800"), but if I have 1 figure it would be very big. if I have 3 or 4 they get smaller.
please see a part of my code:

```
#UI section
plotOutput("fancyPlot",  inline = F, height = "800")

#Server section
 output$fancyPlot <- renderPlot({
#I get the plot_list_final which has some plots (1 or 2 or 3 or 4).
              n <-  lenght(plot_list_final )
              nCol <- floor(sqrt(n))
              p_last =  do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list_final, ncol=nCol))
              return(p_last) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do every plot in your `grid.arrange` individually, for example inside `fluidPage` with `splitLayout`. In this case, you have separate figure for each plot. UI is generated with `renderUI` in this case to have capability of adjustment for number of rows and columns.

Here is the solution:

```
n <- 4 #(1 or 2 or 3 or 4)
nCol <- floor(sqrt(n))
nRow <- ceiling(n/nCol)
height <- "800"

ui <- fluidPage(
      uiOutput("plotgrid")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotgrid <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:nRow, function(k) {
      do.call(splitLayout,
              c(lapply(1:nCol,
                       function(l) {
                         plotOutput(paste("plot", k, l, sep = "-"), height = height)
                       })
              )
      )
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    lapply(1:nRow, function(k) {
      lapply(1:nCol,
             function(l) {
               if (k*l <= n) {
                 output[[paste("plot", k, l, sep = "-")]] <- renderPlot({
                   # this is your plot
                   plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
                 })
               }
             })
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```